# Xcode Instruments gives this error "Could not start script, target application is not frontmost."

Tags: xcode, user-interface, automation

I am using Xcode version 5.0 and trying to use instruments,when i am running  the script which contains "var target = UIATarget.localTarget();"

the following error appears :" Could not start script, target application is not frontmost."

Comment: Same here on Xcode 5.0.2, OSX 10.9

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue:

> The message “Could Not Start Script : Target app is not frontmost” may be displayed when attempting to capture a UI Automation script in Instruments against the iOS 7 Simulator.
>   If this occurs, close the trace document and create a new one. 15387075

Source: [Xcode 5.0.2 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/)

Comment: but in my case, restarting Instruments does not help :(